# WCF web service - increase timeout

Tags: c#, wcf

I get this:

> An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/PersistencyService/Service1/. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

Why do I get this? I assume it is because the method takes about 1 min to complete. How can disable any time limit?

I get this when running in VS a Windows form project that uses a WCF service in the same solution

My WCF configuration:
**edit:**

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="LongRunning" sendTimeout="00:10:00" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
      <endpoint name="Default"          
                address="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/PersistencyService/Service1/"         
                binding="wsHttpBinding"                    
                bindingConfiguration="LongRunning"
                contract="PersistencyService.IService1" />
   </client>
   <services>
      <service name="PersistencyService.Service1">
         <endpoint 
             address="" 
             binding="wsHttpBinding"  bindingConfiguration=""
             contract="PersistencyService.IService1" >
             <identity>
                <dns value="localhost" />
             </identity>
         </endpoint>
         <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
         <host>
            <baseAddresses>
               <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8732/Design_Time_Addresses/PersistencyService/Service1/" />
            </baseAddresses>
         </host>
      </service>
   </services>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```

The exception message is An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
I must also add that I get about 70MB of data from the service

Comment: Hi Ryan, as long as you call a "timeout" time limit you will not have much luck googling on this ;-) :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the client side, you need to add some settings to your `app.config`:

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
         <binding name="LongRunning" sendTimeout="00:10:00" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <client>
       <endpoint name="Default"
           address="....."
           binding="wsHttpBinding"
           bindingConfiguration="LongRunning"
           contract="IYourServiceContract" />
   </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

You didn't give us much to go on - no config, nothing.... so I'm left just guessing what settings you might have.

Basically, you need to define a **binding configuration** for the type of binding you're using, and you need to increase the `sendTimeout` attribute on that binding configuration (here in my sample: 10 minutes). You cannot completely turn off the timeout - you can increase it, but not turn it off.

Then, your client side config must make a reference to that binding configuration you've defined, by specifying a `bindingConfiguration="...."` attribute on the `<endpoint>` configuration, and using the same name for the binding configuration as when you defined it.

Maybe this is enough - but maybe, you'll also need to increase some of the timeouts on the *server* side. Try this first - if it doesn't work, come back and ask again - and **please**, next time: provide us with some more useful info, like your code and config!

Comment: I've added the config file. I still get this error and I don't know why

Comment: @Ryan: Ok you're using basicHttpBinding - did you adapt my config accordingly??

Comment: I've eddited with the new config. I tryed to match your code . If something is not the same please tell me! I still have the same problem. I use the discovery button to add a refference to the service in the same solution. Thanks or your help so far and hope you can help me!

Comment: @Ryan: can you show us your service contract with the service, and how you're calling the service from your client code? Config seems fine to me...

Comment: I think it is because of the very large data I need to get trough the service. can I increase that somehow?

Comment: @Ryan: Ok, in that case, I would recommend trying to set `<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>` for now and see if you can get back a fault from the service that gives you an idea what is going wrong...